# Changing a caret button on hovering over its parent element

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, accordion, font-awesome

I have an accordion that I would like to change an icon inside an accordion when the mouse hovers over the anchor tag

```
<div class="accordion-group panel">
    <div class="accordion-heading">
         <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse292"> 
            <i></i> Course Curriculum 
         </a>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse292" class="accordion-body collapse in" style="height: auto;">
        <div class="accordion-inner"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have the following in my css code and I am using fontawesome for displaying carets using the content css property but I cannot figure out how i can target the icon to change to another caret and change the color of its background when i hover over the anchor tag element.

```
.accordion-heading a {
    font-size: 14px;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    padding: 14px 20px 10px 0;
    font-weight: 600;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #EFEFEF;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #cbcbcb;
    padding-left: 12px;
    color: #333333;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .35);
}

.accordion-heading a.accordion-toggle:after {
    background: #949494;
}

.accordion-heading a:hover{
    background: #65b72f;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255, .2);
};

.accordion-heading a.accordion-toggle:after {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    float: right;
    font-size: 22px;
    color: #EFEFEF;
    content: "\f0d7";
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-decoration: inherit;
    padding:6px 17px 6px 12px;
    height: 44px;
    margin-top: -14px;
    margin-right: -19px;
    box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0, .2), 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255, .1);
}
.accordion-heading a.accordion-toggle.collapsed:after{
    content: "\f0da";
    padding-left: 17px;
    padding-right: 17px;
    height: 44px;
    margin-top: -14px;
    margin-right: -19px;
    font-size: 22px;
}
.accordion-inner{
    padding:15px 0;
}
```

I can't post the code to jsbin or some other side but here is the url where the code is working [here](http://183.83.67.105/skillspeed/course/android-app-development/)

Comment: Are you able to use javascript / jQuery?  Here is a fiddle with an example:  http://jsfiddle.net/5gsh9532/  Not sure if that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* you're caret goes in the `i` tag. If so, would something like this suffice?

It's using the css selector:

```
    .accordion-toggle:hover i
```

```css
.accordion-heading a {
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  padding: 14px 20px 10px 0;
  font-weight: 600;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #EFEFEF;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #cbcbcb;
  padding-left: 12px;
  color: #333333;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, .35);
}
.accordion-heading a.accordion-toggle:after {
  background: #949494;
}
.accordion-heading a:hover {
  background: #65b72f;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
}
;
 .accordion-heading a.accordion-toggle:after {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  float: right;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #EFEFEF;
  content: "\f0d7";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-decoration: inherit;
  padding: 6px 17px 6px 12px;
  height: 44px;
  margin-top: -14px;
  margin-right: -19px;
  box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), 1px 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
}
.accordion-heading a.accordion-toggle.collapsed:after {
  content: "\f0da";
  padding-left: 17px;
  padding-right: 17px;
  height: 44px;
  margin-top: -14px;
  margin-right: -19px;
  font-size: 22px;
}
.accordion-inner {
  padding: 15px 0;
}

.accordion-toggle:hover i{
background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="accordion-group panel">
  <div class="accordion-heading">
    <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse292">
      <i>this?</i> Course Curriculum
    </a>
  </div>
  <div id="collapse292" class="accordion-body collapse in" style="height: auto;">
    <div class="accordion-inner"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Np. Just glad i could help :)

Answer (score 3):

I resolved the problem only with css, if I understood correctly the task.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/02w0fuxq/) is the solution.

Here are your css rules `.accordion-heading a.accordion-toggle.collapsed:after` and `.accordion-heading a.accordion-toggle:after`. These rules you have to merge them to `.accordion-heading a.accordion-toggle.collapsed:after` and add to ".accordion-heading a.accordion-toggle.collapsed:after" the :hover selector. with the other `content: ""` rule, should look like this : `.accordion-heading a.accordion-toggle.collapsed:hover:after`.

The following css works for me:

```
.accordion-heading a {
    font-size: 14px;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    padding: 14px 20px 10px 0;
    font-weight: 600;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #EFEFEF;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #cbcbcb;
    padding-left: 12px;
    color: #333333;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .35);
}

.accordion-heading a.accordion-toggle:after {
    background: #949494;
}

.accordion-heading a:hover{
    background: #65b72f;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255, .2);
}

.accordion-heading a.accordion-toggle.collapsed:after {
    content: "test";
    padding-left: 17px;
    padding-right: 17px;
    height: 44px;
    margin-top: -14px;
    margin-right: -19px;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-decoration: inherit;
    padding:6px 17px 6px 12px;
    height: 44px;
    margin-top: -14px;
    margin-right: -19px;
    box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0, .2), 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255, .1);
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-size: 22px;
    color: #EFEFEF;
}
.accordion-heading a.accordion-toggle.collapsed:hover:after{
    content: "something";
    padding-left: 17px;
    padding-right: 17px;
    height: 44px;
    margin-top: -14px;
    margin-right: -19px;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-decoration: inherit;
    padding:6px 17px 6px 12px;
    height: 44px;
    margin-top: -14px;
    margin-right: -19px;
    box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0, .2), 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255, .1);
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-size: 22px;
    color: #EFEFEF;
}
.accordion-inner{
    padding:15px 0;
}
```

I hope my explication was understandable.